# What is the eigenvalue of $J_z$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, eigenvalue

In the calculation of the Zeeman Effect, the most important calculation is

$$\langle J_z + S_z\rangle.$$

Suppose we want to find the Zeeman Effect for $(2p)^2$, meaning $l = 1$.

In Sakurai's book,

[image]

My question is, what is $m$? They say that $m$ is the eigenvalue of $J_z$, meaning $J_z = l + m_s = \frac{3}{2}$ in this case.

But this gives the wrong Gordon-Clebsch coefficients:

$$|\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}|1\rangle|-\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}|0\rangle|+\rangle.$$

Comment: There's several perhaps typos that makes this question confusing: on the last line, is $|1,1 \rangle |= \rangle$ a 3-particle state or what? Also why is the operator $J_z$ given by a sum of scalars?

Comment: $|1,1\rangle$ means $|l,m_l\rangle$

I'm actually adding orbital angular momentum $(l=1)$ with spin angular momentum $(\pm \frac{1}{2})$ of an electron.

Actually it can be simplified to: $|\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}|1\rangle|-\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}|0\rangle|+\rangle$